# MPL replace without casting the fusion container

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-mpl, boost-fusion

I have this class

```
struct MyChildrenNeedsSpace : HaveChildren<MyChildrenNeedsSpace>
{
    typedef childrenListType<string, string, string, string> context;

    const   context children;

    MyChildrenNeedsSpace() : children("this", "sentence", "needs", "spaces")
    {
        std::cout << endl << "The children type is:"  << endl << typeid(children).name() << endl;
    }
};
```

it uses CRTP to allow the HaveChildren class to access its children member variable.

The childrenListType is a class that inherits from boost::fusion::vector.

I would like to programmatically make the children member variable contain one space class between each string.

So if I enter:

```
<string,string>
```

children becomes:

```
<string, space,string>
```

If I enter:

> ```
> <string,string,string>
> ```

it becomes

> ```
> <string,space,string,space,string>
> ```

etc.

I am using boost fusion so it have to be at compile time.

I have tried to do it like this:

```c++
struct MyChildrenNeedsSpaceWithReplacer : HaveChildren<MyChildrenNeedsSpaceWithReplacer>
{
    typedef childrenListType<string, string, string, string> context;
    typedef boost::mpl::replace< context, string, stringAndSpace >::type replacedContext;

    const   replacedContext children;

    MyChildrenNeedsSpaceWithReplacer() : children( "this" ,"sentence" , "needs" , "spaces")
    {
        std::cout << endl << "The children type is:" << endl <<typeid(children).name() << endl;
    }
};
```

But then the MPL:replace changes the type of the container from my own class, that inherits from boost::fusion::vector, to a boost::fusion::vector4 and that ruins my streaming overloaders.

You may notice that instead of having `<string,space>` I replace each string with a `stringAndSpace`.

Having `<string,space>` would be best- but the other way was easier for me.

So- to summarise:

```
typedef boost::mpl::replace< context, string, stringAndSpace >::type replacedContext;
```

casts my container type- can you help to make a function that can at compile time define a type be the following class

```
struct childrenListType : public  boost::fusion::vector<CHILDREN_TYPES...>
```

with template arguments of one space between every string I input?

I have posted the full source at: http://ideone.com/XxYTOt

Their compilers typeinfo says that without the mpl replace the children type is: `16childrenListTypeIISsSsSsSsEE`

and with : `N5boost6fusion7vector4I14stringAndSpaceS2_S2_S2_EE`

You can also see the stream overloads fails because it outputs the parenthesis around:

```
(this  sentence  needs  spaces )
```

Comment: Don't get it, why not just add the spaces at the point where you stream everything out - if you know that each element has to be separated by a space? Also I imagine that your streaming functionality is broken if you can't handle *tuples* of varying sizes?

Comment: The code I have pasted here is only to show the concept that I want to solve.

Comment: It is not really about just getting it to output the correct thing- I am starting to learn MPL and is stucked here so I was hoping somebody might say something like "oh, you just have to use boost::XXXXX instead" or show me the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++14, I fail to see the need for boost here - or maybe I'm missing one of your requirements? The following will add spaces between the types with plain C++14:

```
struct space {};
template<typename, typename=void> struct spacer;

template<template<typename...> class T>
struct spacer<T<>> { using type = T<>; };

template<template<typename...> class T,typename T1, typename... Ts>
struct spacer<T<T1,Ts...>>
    : spacer<T<T1,Ts...>, std::make_index_sequence<2*sizeof...(Ts)+1>> {};

template<template<typename...> class T,typename... Ts, std::size_t... Ns>
struct spacer<T<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Ns...>>
{
    using tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    using type =
        T<std::conditional_t<(Ns%2)==0,std::tuple_element_t<Ns/2,tuple>,space>...>;
};

template<typename T> using spacer_t = typename spacer<T>::type;
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e73a9c477502e8e3)

The above preserves your outer container type, so in your case if you pass in a `boost::fusion::vector<...>`, this is also what you'll get as a result (just with additional `space`s).

Comment: With C++14, I fail to see the need for boost here - or maybe I'm missing one of your requirements?

Comment: @Hansvesselgård Um... if I missed a requirement, then please spell it out for me, don't just repeat what I said. Thanks.

Comment: "With C++14, I fail to see the need for boost here - or maybe I'm missing one of your requirements?" Oh, this is just some snippets from a larger codebase and with some stub/dummy code I made for making it easier for people to understand the issue when I ask for help.
I am new at TMP so I do not know all the correct words- so I prefer showing what I want to do. 
" if I missed a requirement, then please spell it out for me, don't just repeat what I said. Thanks" You understood me perfectly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer- I am amazed. I am going to need some time to really understand the code. 
I am watching  Walter E. Brown "Modern Template Metaprogramming: A Compendium " and reading alot to get a better understanding of modern template meta programming. There are alot of concepts I need to understand and not alot of learning aids for the newest stuff( like the make_index_sequence ). 

My current strategy was to implement the following  algo as a template function using either paramter packs or typelists as containers but your was is much smarter,
http://ideone.com/IPiSQm

Comment: @Hansvesselgård Ah, OK. Well, in that case I'm glad I could help. From my experience, it is worth to learn about variadic templates, TMP, etc. without the help of external libraries first (but of course including the standard library). It is mostly a requirement to understand the basics yourself before you are able to fully utilize more complex libraries like MPL, etc. - and often those libraries are not even needed so solve most problems you'll encounter in real life.

Comment: Your code helped me in the right direction- but I could not make it compile in Visual Studio 2015. Line 18 gives error C2971: 'std::tuple_element': template parameter '_Index': '_Index': a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument. In my attempts to fix it other errors comes. So I ended up making it without the make_integer_sequence. If others reads this post it might help them: http://ideone.com/kQgr7d